# Add bot (ms-botbuilder) to the MS Teams Team/Channel programmatically

Tags: botframework, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-teams

I'm looking to find a way to add a bot to a team that this bot just created.

1. Was able to create a group via MS Graph by the bot 
   JS-SDK

```
graphClient.api("/groups").post({
            displayName: "Some Name",
            mailNickname: "Name without Spaces",
            description: "Some Description",
            visibility: "Private",
            groupTypes: ["Unified"],
            mailEnabled: true,
            securityEnabled: false,
            "members@odata.bind": members, // array of url strings of members
            "owners@odata.bind": owners,
        });
```

`members` and `owners` arrays of strings representing users: 
`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user-id}`. Found them via `/users` search

2. then added a team to this group 
   (source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/team-put-teams?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=javascript) like that: 
   `` graphClient.api(`/groups/${group-id}/team`).put({}); ``
3. and channel - `` graphClient.api(`/teams/${group-id}/channels`).post(channel); ``

Couldn't find a way to add the bot to the team or channel that was just created. 
Maybe there is a way to locate it guid or some kind of app-id and add it to the group?

Comment: I haven't looked into this much, but I know there are a few complexities in it. In short I think you should be looking at the "installedApps" collection, I think. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/teamsappinstallation-add?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) for more info. The appId here is not your normal app id though, it's the one from the [app catalog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/teamsapp-list?view=graph-rest-1.0), if I recall correctly. Not a complete answer as I haven't worked with this enough, but hopefully enough to set you in the right direction.

Comment: Hi @HiltonGiesenow. Thanks a lot! it worked. You are correct. Not exactly adding a bot as a member of the group, but I guess in Teams it's not a case anyway. 
The steps are: 
1. add your app to the [App catalogue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/deploy-and-publish/appsource/publish#microsoft-teams-tenant-app-catalog) or [add as a custom app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/deploy-and-publish/apps-upload)
2. things you have described.
If you want to formulate it as an answer, I'm happy to accept it as the correct one.

Comment: glad to hear! Will post a full answer below

Comment: @HiltonGiesenow, Yes you are correct. Here is the documentation for [installing app in team](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/teamsappinstallation-add?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) using graph API.

Comment: great, thanks for confirming - it's something on my list to play more with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So remember that a Bot is not a regular user, it's an App. As a result, to add it to a Team, you would use the [Add app to team](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/teamsappinstallation-add?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) operation against the Graph. To do so, you need to use the app Id from [List the published apps from the Microsoft Teams app catalog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/teamsapp-list?view=graph-rest-1.0).

Once you do this, your bot is part of the entire Team, and can be accessed from any Channel. As a result, you don't need to also add your bot to a Channel per se after installing it to the Team (you can see this because the only way to remove the bot from a "channel" is by removing it from the App tab for the entire Team). It's kind of like a user in this regard - adding the user to the Team gives them access to all channels. However, if your app includes a tab as well, the tab can be added automatically to an individual channel - see [add tab to channel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/teamstab-add?view=graph-rest-1.0).