# MS-Teams Create Teams App with out using App Studio UI interface

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

Need to create MS Teams App creation trough script or an MS Teams API

Currently, we are creating the below steps manually through MS Teams site

1. Build a new App / configure BOT
2. Import existing App

Is there a way without accessing MS Teams App studio, can we create an App?

Comment: you can use microsoft teams toolkit for VSCode https://alfilatov.com/posts/how-to-create-debug-and-deploy-your-ms-teams-apps-using-vscode/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question's not really to clear, perhaps you can explain more. Basically though, App Studio helps with a few different things. In this case you're probably using it for the following:

1) Creating an app manifest - App Studio has a nice "wizard" to help create the manifest, but the manifest is just a zip file with some logo images and a JSON file inside - you can definitely create these without App Studio (but it's much nicer to do it inside App Studio - you can export it afterwards to get the zip file)

2) Installing your app - you -definitely- don't need App Studio for this. You can install  your app in various ways. The most simple for a user, of course, is to be in the store, but even without that it's possible. The app needs to be "side-loaded", and you can do this in App Studio, or in the "Apps" list in Teams (right on the bottom of the left menu is an option to "upload a custom app") - for both of these, your organisation has to allow side loading of apps to Teams. If this is blocked, then you admin needs to side-load the app and make it available company-wide (or it can be restricted based on policies at https://admin.teams.microsoft.com/policies/app-setup/add)

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes you are correct, we can a Json file using App Studio wizard and can be downloaded. In Next step we are looking for a script/API to Create Teams App as process of our automation script with using MS Teams Wizard to import Json for creating App.

Comment: Glad to help. It sounds like you might also be looking, once the app is side-loaded to the company "store", about how to automatically add the app into a specific team(s)? If so, see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59796925/add-bot-ms-botbuilder-to-the-ms-teams-team-channel-programmatically/59807576#59807576

Comment: Yes, you are right. I saw your answer  for Add app to team through Graph API, this will help me in next step. I was also looking how can we use Json file to create App? Is there a way using Graph API?

Comment: Not sure what you mean about using the JSON file to "Create" app?

Answer (score 0):

@MSTD Creating a Teams app can be done in 2 ways

1. Manually editing the [manifest file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/schema/manifest-schema) in the solution, zip it and  sideloading it into Teams.
2. Using [App studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/apps-package) to create the app.

Currently, there is no API/Script to create the app package.

Comment: thank you. we are looking for a script/API to Create Teams App as process of our automation script.