# Error:This method is only valid within the scope of ms teams team

Tags: node.js, botframework, microsoft-teams

I get an error as mentioned in the title when i use Teamsinfo's getTeamChannels and getTeamsDetail methods
where as when i use TeamsInfo.getMembers. The code works fine perfectly.

im using msteams to send messages hence the scope issue shouldnt really come up. Also getMembers works totally fine. not sure why the other two doesn't

Code without issue-

```
export class MyBot extends TeamsActivityHandler {
    constructor() {
        super();

        // See https://aka.ms/about-bot-activity-message to learn more about the message and other activity types.
        this.onMessage(async (turnContext, next) => {
            const members = await TeamsInfo.getMembers(turnContext);

            // By calling next() you ensure that the next BotHandler is run.
            await next();
        });
    }
}
```

Code with issue-

```
export class MyBot extends TeamsActivityHandler {
    constructor() {
        super();

        // See https://aka.ms/about-bot-activity-message to learn more about the message and other activity types.
        this.onMessage(async (turnContext, next) => {

            const teamDetails = await TeamsInfo.getTeamDetails(turnContext);


            // By calling next() you ensure that the next BotHandler is run.
            await next();
        });
    }
}
```

Any known issue? 
Versions:"botbuilder-azure": "^4.7.2",
"botbuilder": "^4.7.2"

Comment: Where is the bot deployed? Is it in an actual Teams channel, or perhaps elsewhere (like a 1-1 chat with a user, or a group chat)?

Comment: Actual teams channel? I had registered the bot for ms teams through legacy portal ,hardly took few minutes. And in my Teams i added the bot as a one-to-one after searching with the  App Id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments above, I think I've got an answer:

"getMembers" is working because, in a 1-1 chat (just you and the bot), there are "members" of the conversation. However, there are 3 different kinds of chats a bot can participate in:

1) a "1-1", like you're having now
2) a "group chat", where there's a direct chat between, for example, you, one or more other users, and the bot (this will also appear in the "chat" section on the left menu in Teams)
3) A "channel" inside a "Team" in Teams. For instance, you might have a team like "Finance" with a "channel" like "Accounts receivable", and your bot can be connected to this team+channel

The methods you're calling depend on where the bot conversation is taking place. For instance, "getTeamDetails" will only work in scenario (3) above, where the bot is actually **in** a team.

Hope that helps explain?

Comment: i see, that does help .Also could you please help me out with one more thing. I was looking into sending proactive messages to a specific user from another user's context. The code from the microsoft documentation  as shown below on proactive-
    
var msg = new builder.Message().address(address);
msg.text('Hello, this is a notification');
bot.send(msg);   Would these be added in the index.js of the bot?

Comment: great, glad to help. Please "mark as answer" or upvote so it can help others in future. With regards your other question, I work mostly with C#, so not 100% sure on the JS solution, but there's a working sample at https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/16.proactive-messages that should hopefully help. If not, ask it as a separate question so others can see it more clearly

Comment: Hi Hilton ,need your help .How do we add bot into teams channel? not one to one ..but into a channel.

Comment: Have a look here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59796925/add-bot-ms-botbuilder-to-the-ms-teams-team-channel-programmatically . Please "upvote" if it helps you.